# Reference Error on Angular, button not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an angular project and I want to link a function from `projects.component.ts`, so when I make a click on a button on `projects.component.html` it calls that function. But when I click on the button.

I have this error message on chrome's console:
[image: Code]

This is my html:

[image: code from projects.component.html]

This is my TS:

[image: code from projects.component.ts]

Comment: You need to swap onclick for (click).- https://angular.io/guide/user-input hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your HTML to the following :

```
<button type="button" (click)="infoTic.mirar()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the ✔ icon below the question to close the loop. 